# CVSROOT problem because of username string

Tags: cygwin, cvs

I have always been SVN user but currently I have to use CVS as the source repository. I am quite new to CVS and really got confused many a times (reason being I always tried to access CVS like SVN !)

However now I am really stuck in one problem wherein I am not able to do any cvs operations through cygwin. Actually I have checked out the code using WinCVS and while doing that it created the CVSROOT as following,

`:pserver;username=<user_name>;password=<pwd>:<serverip>:/cvs/repository`

However whenever I try to use cvs command in cygwin (after setting CVSROOT variable using export) it fails with following error:

```
cvs update: Unknown option (`username') in CVSROOT.
cvs update: in directory .:
cvs update: ignoring CVS/Root because it does not contain a valid root.
cvs update: Unknown option (`username') in CVSROOT.
cvs [update aborted]: Bad CVSROOT: `:pserver;username=<user_name>;password=<pwd>:<serverip>:/cvs/repository'.
```

However the command works fine, if invoked through dos command prompt. I got to know that on DOS prompt, cvs command is provided by CVSNT whereas in cygwin it's some different package.

Please let me know where I have made a mistake and how it can be corrected !

I need cvs to work inside cygwin for some scripting purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely looking for a connection in the form: `:pserver:<user_name>@<serverip>:/cvs/repository`.

You can test with the command `cvs -d :pserver:<user_name>@<serverip>:/cvs/repository login`.

If you try to use the same sandbox for both windows and cygwin you will may have problems.